# How to correct the c++ code below?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
class A1{
    public void op(){cout << "A1";}
};

class B1 : public A1{
    public void op(){cout << "B1";}
};
```

Seems valid to me,but the compiler is reporting :

Error,expected a ':' at `void`

Answer (score 5):

```
class A1
{
    public:
       virtual void op(){cout << "A1";}
};

class B1 : public A1
{
    public:
       void op(){cout << "B1";}
};
```

Beware to add the keyword `virtual`, otherwise, you are not overriding `void op();` in B

Comment: virtual destructor is also required for `A1`

Comment: @Naveen: yes, you should add a virtual destructor but it's not strictly necessary in this very special case since there are no data members.

Comment: To answer the question, we might stress Visage's answer: semi-colons are needed after `public` keyword. Virtual destructor missing will only be involved when considering memory leaks, not compilation. It should generate warnings though.

Comment: @jack alright, but more than obviously he wanted to put inheritance in practice  :-) I don't think it may generate a warning because it **is** legal c++, and I think the technique is called "masking" member functions.

Comment: I dont think answers should change the semantics of the OP's code - he asked about a compilation error, not runtime behaviour. Hence adding virtual is wrong.

Comment: @Visage, oh guy, you have made me laugh really with your "Hence.. is wrong"... Here we obviously are answering to a **total novice beginer** in C++ who doesn't even know how to declare a member function in C++...

Comment: @yoyo Because it's actually masking `op()`, not overriding it. Do this and you'll see it fail: `A1& inst = B1(); inst.op();`.

Comment: @Perdo, well it will not fail, but it will call the wrong member function, the one member of A instead of the one member of B. Polymorphism is at stake only when the `virtual` keyword is used.

Answer (score 4):

Colons after the public labels.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A1 { public: void op () {cout << "A1";}};

class B1 : public A1 { public: void op () {cout << "B1"; }};
```

PS. Also may be you want to use virtual methods?

Answer (score 2):

```
class A1{
        public: void op(){cout << "A1";}
};

class B1 : public A1{
        public: void op(){cout << "B1";}
};
```

:) C++ has a different syntax than C#. In C++ it's less verbose, so you can do:

```
class A1{
public:
    void a(){cout << "x";}
    void b(){cout << "x";}
    void c(){cout << "x";}
};
```

instead of having to put public in front of all public methods.